# How to replace space into &nbsp in Django template?

Tags: django, templates, space

I have a model with multiline text fields, which was input from a `textarea`.

Now I want to render the field, but don't want to use `<pre>` tag.

I just want to replace the new line with `<br/>`, and I found the `linebreakbr` filter.

But I also want to replace space with `&nbsp;`. Seemed not included in the documentation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't u want to use `pre`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django templates stripping spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721035/django-templates-stripping-spaces)

Comment: @alecxe because it have some global style on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For replacing a space with &nbsp , you may use one of following Template Tags based solution:

1) [nbsp filter](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2842/)
Replaces usual spaces in string by non breaking spaces

2) [Regular Expression Replace Template Filter](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/60/)
This will perform a regular expression search/replace on a string in your template.

3) [Stackoverflow post, @Paolo Bergantino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721035/django-templates-stripping-spaces)
Suggests to make a custom template tag

Comment: Note that the nbsp filter in your first link lacks escaping of the value itself. It should say `mark_safe("&nbsp;".join(conditional_escape(value).split(' ')))`.

Comment: @Flash's comment is a good one. You'll need to add `from django.utils.html import conditional_escape`

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
.nbsp {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="nbsp">Any text you want</div>
```

This should also help without processing text on server side.

Comment: Note this does not have the same effect as actual `&nbsp;` characters, most notably for trailing spaces, which don't add to the width of a text element, while trailing `&nbsp;` characters do.