# Django automatic remove whitespace in drop-down or select widget

Tags: python, django, templates

django (1.10) removes automatic whitespaces in strings if they where displayed in a Listbox, dropdown or select widget.
Example: original string is
"Madrid       Spain"
is displayed as
"Madrid Spain".
This happens in my forms but also in the management forms.

But I want to format my selection by 2 columns with 5 or more whitespaces as separator.
I'm using the default render-settings:
..
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
..

Thanks for any suggestions
Regards
Martin

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721035/django-templates-stripping-spaces

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Martin